# How to reload the page if element doesn't appear in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

At times due to time out or other reason the page stops loading or gets loaded but the signup page doesn't appear, to make sure it appears we have to refresh the page, I have tried driver.navigate.refresh(), I have tried explicit wait and javascript executor, nothing works, I am adding the snippet of what I have tried, but it doesn't work either.
My scripts fails once the findelement().isdisplayed is false, it is not going in the if loop.
Below is the code-

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {   
        System.out.println("In for loop");
        try
        {
        if(driver.findElement(byusername).isDisplayed())
        {
            System.out.println("Element found");
            driver.findElement(byusername).sendKeys(username);
            driver.findElement(bypassword).sendKeys(password);
            driver.findElement(signIn).click();
            System.out.println("Logged in");
            basewait.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(Tab));
            System.out.println("Wait completed, going to base class");
            i=3;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Element not found"+i+" try");
            driver.navigate().refresh();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            i++;
        }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: what is the error are you getting when element is not displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
if(driver.findElement(byusername).isDisplayed())
```

with:

```
if(driver.findElements(byusername).size() > 0 && driver.findElements(byusername).get(0).isDisplayed())
```

This won't throw exception and you can go to `else` statement. `driver.findElements(byusername)` return a list of elements found and if no elements were found it returns just an empty list.

Comment: This helps my base class to reload the page if the array is empty, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that an implicit wait only needs to be set one time, after the instantiation of your web driver, unless for whatever reason you wanted to later change the timeout value of that setting.

Second, try using the below code to wait for the page to finish loading.

```
/**
 * Wait for the web page to finish loading
 */
public void waitForPageToLoad() {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

        public Boolean apply(WebDriver wdriver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
}
```